# iOS 14 inline DatePicker in expandable cell constraints conflict

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datepicker, autolayout

I'm struggling to create expandable/collapsible UITableView cell with inline DatePicker.

I'm using autolayout and combination of constraint and autoresizing masks, with stack view containing collapsed and expanded views. Collapsed view contains two labels and have fixed height of 44 pt, expanded view contains inline DatePicker.
[image]

So going up in view hierarchy, DatePicker has 4 constraints with 0's equal to his parent view (Detail View). Detail view has autoresizing masks enabled to all sizes, stack view has 4 constraints with 0's equal to his parent view (Full View), Full view also has autoresizing masks enabled.

When running in simulator, i got few xcode error logs similar to this one, about being unable to satisfy DatePicker's inner collection view.

```
2021-08-10 20:13:29.154296+0500 Meeting-Room[37194:820026] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001324e0 UIView:0x7f92c1c6b1e0.height >= 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000148d70 _UIDatePickerCalendarContentStackView:0x7f92c1c22750.bottom <= UILayoutGuide:0x600001b2f1e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000148d20 _UIDatePickerCalendarContentStackView:0x7f92c1c22750.top == UILayoutGuide:0x600001b2f1e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000121d10 V:|-(0)-[_UIDatePickerCalendarView:0x7f92c1c22570]   (active, names: '|':UIDatePicker:0x7f92c1c0d2c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000121d60 _UIDatePickerCalendarView:0x7f92c1c22570.bottom == UIDatePicker:0x7f92c1c0d2c0.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000121e50 V:|-(0)-[UIDatePicker:0x7f92c1c0d2c0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f92c1c065c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000121ea0 V:[UIDatePicker:0x7f92c1c0d2c0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f92c1c065c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000121f40 V:[UIStackView:0x7f92c1c1d530]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f92c1c6dc70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000121f90 V:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7f92c1c1d530]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f92c1c6dc70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000012dfe0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7f92c1c1d530.top == UIView:0x7f92c1c6b1e0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000010c910 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIView:0x7f92c1c065c0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7f92c1c1d530 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000015c550 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIView:0x7f92c1c6b1e0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f92c1c065c0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000148be0 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001b2f1e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerCalendarView:0x7f92c1c22570 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000012e300 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f92c1c6dc70.height == 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000148a50 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600001b2f1e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerCalendarView:0x7f92c1c22570 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000148d70 _UIDatePickerCalendarContentStackView:0x7f92c1c22750.bottom <= UILayoutGuide:0x600001b2f1e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom   (active)>
```

In the running app cell expanding/collapsing and layout works almost as expected, except current date icon, thats looks like ellipse at inital appear, but transforms to circle after any interaction with DatePicker.

I'm spent few days stumbled upon this problem and don't know what else to try, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: A bit confusing... in the image you posted, it looks like you're **Presenting** a view controller - table view controller with a single row? So it's not at all clear what you're  you're doing that you are expanding / collapsing?

Comment: Yes, table view controller has 2 rows, i've manually set this number  in numberOfRowsInSection since this table view created purely for cell testing. For expanding/collapsing, i'm toggling .isHidden of cell's detailView in didSelectRowAt func.

Comment: Not sure, without seeing your code, but one thing to try: set the `Priority` of your `bottom = Stack View.bottom` constraint to `999`

Comment: Added priority to constraint, no difference... I've created separate project only for this cell could you please look at it? In last version i've added fixed date picker height constraint >= 380, all log warning disappear with it, but i've got extra free space in cell on devices with small screens like iPod Touch 7. https://github.com/vwf12/ExpandableCellWithDatePicker

Comment: Give this a try... add an `Aspect Ratio` constraint of `75:76` to the DatePicker https://i.stack.imgur.com/IESbJ.png and then remove the `>= 380` height constraint https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsT9A.png ... On several formats (iPhone 8, 8 Plus, 11, and iPod 7th gen), and the only case where I get auto-layout errors / warnings is on the iPod. The error **appears** to be on an internal constraint, which is out of our hands. But, it does get rid of the extra vertical space on the iPod screen size.

Comment: That helped to resolve the issue, thanks a lot! I addressed the issue with warnings on different screen by setting different aspect ratio constraint depending on device screen size with func like this`let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        switch screenWidth {
        case _ where screenWidth <= 320.0:
            datePicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePicker.widthAnchor, multiplier: 77/75).isActive = true
        default:
            datePicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePicker.widthAnchor, multiplier: 76/75).isActive = true
        }`